# Can i make a phone call at my Lenovo A5500-H tablet?

Tags: calls, tablet, lenovo

I have a Lenovo A5500-H tablet with a sim card slot and i want to know if i can make calls on it.  I hope you can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

According to some [sources](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and/Lenovo-A5500-H-A8-50/td-p/1583592), the H variant cannot make voice calls, instead it supports Wi-Fi and data (2g/3g) hence the sim slot.

As stated by one user on [XDA forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/lenovo-a8-5500-hv-a8-5500-h-roms-t2836866):

This tablets comes in 3 ROM variants; the *F, H and HV*.

Lenovo H variants are made with the same hardware as their HV variants but a different ROM. H's have 3g data & wifi **but not voice calling**, HV's have 3d data & wifi & voice calling.

Some users have found a workaround to enable voice calling using some unofficial means:

> With most a Lenovo's recent tablets, if you have the 'H' model (3G
>   data only), you can load the firmware for the 'HV' model (3G data with
>   calling) and it will work.

In case you wish to understand more on this topic, read detailed instructions provided on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/lenovo-a8-5500-hv-a8-5500-h-roms-t2836866)